# Detecting patterns in subsets of a large dataset in R systematically

Tags: r, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I would like to detect patterns within a weather dataset of around 10'000 data points. I have around 40 possible predictors (temperature, humidity etc.) which may explain good or bad weather the next day (dependent variable). Normally, I would apply classical machine learning methods like Random Forest to build and test models for classifying the whole dataset and find reliable predictors to forecast the next day's weather.

My task though is different. I want to find predictors and their parameters which "guarantee" me good or bad weather in a subset of the overall data. I am not interested in describing the whole dataset but finding the pattern of predictors (and their parameters) that give me good or bad weather indications. So I am trying to find, for example, 100 datapoints with 100% good weather if certain predictors are set to certain levels. I am not interested in the other 9'900 datapoints.

It is kind of the task of trying all combinations and calibrations of the predictors to find a subset of the overall data points which can be predicted with very high accuracy.

As described above I would be happy if certain variables definitely cause good or bad weather. For this task
How would you do this systematically?

Comment: You could train a decision tree with binary response (good yes/no). Then, subset on observations with very high probability of good weather and describe their feature distributions.

Comment: "Guarantee".   Suppose that you found some region of the search space that contains 100 points and they are all good weather.  But it could be that the underlying probability of bad weather in that region is 1/200. With that probability,  about 60% of the time a sample of 100 points would contain only good days, but it is still not 100%.  You can never eliminate the possibility of a bad day,  only make it small.